# Resetting / changing the offset of bootstrap affix

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

How do I change the offset of Affix (Twitter Bootstrap 3) to another value?

When I tried to call the method twice like this, the second one seems to be ignored and does not have any effect:

```
$('#navbar-main').affix({ offset: 100});
$('#navbar-main').affix({ offset: 200}); // ---> the offset will not change to 200px
```

Resetting the `.affix` callback before calling `affix` the second time didn't help either:

```
$('#navbar-main').affix({ offset: 100});
$(window).off('.affix');
$('#navbar-main').affix({ offset: 200}); // ---> the offset will not change to 200px
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here's how. The key is to both call `off` on `.affix`, and also, `removeData` on the affix'ed element. Let's say I want to reset the affix of `#navbar-main`:

Bootstrap < 3 (from [es128](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/5870#issuecomment-15785043)):

```
$(window).off('.affix')
$('#navbar-main').removeData('affix').removeClass('affix affix-top affix-bottom')
$('#navbar-main').affix({ offset: 400})
```

Bootstrap 3 (from [Dysko](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/5870#issuecomment-36961257)):

```
$(window).off('.affix')
$('#navbar-main').removeData('bs.affix').removeClass('affix affix-top affix-bottom')
$('#navbar-main').affix({ offset: 400})
```

Comment: I fixed the issue using the next solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23137120/469161

Answer (score 39):

remember, you have access to the constructor at anytime with the data method…

so if you're just trying to update a value… you can do:

```
$('#navbar-main').data('bs.affix').options.offset = newOffset
```

hope that helps <3 fat

Comment: Don't forget that offset is an object with a top/bottom property. I was using .options.offset = x; and not .options.offset.top = x; and my affixed div was going crazy.

Comment: I fixed the issue using the next solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23137120/469161