# setAttribute not working on resize

Tags: javascript, jquery

fellas,
I've looked everywhere with no luck. Can someone help me?
I want to change data-offset-top attribute to two different values depending on the screen size.
It works on reload but I cannot make it work on resize. What am I doing wrong?
Here's the code.

```js
strr();
window.addEventListener('resize', strr);

function strr() {
  if (window.outerWidth <= 767) {
    document.getElementById("navas").setAttribute("data-offset-top", 300);
  } else {
    document.getElementById("navas").setAttribute("data-offset-top", 650);
  }
}
```

btw #navas is a bootstrap nav element with affix.

Good luck!

Comment: Works fine here: https://jsfiddle.net/5m3mrx6j/

Comment: You may have an error that prevents js to work . check your console

Comment: What makes you think it doesn't work? What effect is changing that attribute supposed to have?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18702376/how-to-get-dynamic-data-offset-values-for-bootstrap-3-affix-method

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22080346/bootstrap-affix-dynamically-on-resize

Comment: Did you tried `$('#navas').affix('checkPosition')` ?